# "So must I" or "so do I" in place of "of course"

Tags: grammar

Which of these can we use instead of *of course*?

> A: You always obey your parents!
>
> B: (Of course / So must I / So do I), because they are my parents.

Comment: Or   A: You speak excellent Turkish.  B: So......( must I, should I, do I, much more or would I)! I have lived in Ankara for ten years.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be a simple matter of inversion.

> A: You always obey your parents!
>
> B: (Of course / So must I / So do I), because they are my parents.

More natural English would be to change the position of the pronoun (I):

> "So I must, because they are my parents"
>
> "So I do, because they are my parents."

Or even, more naturally and less formally::

> "I must do so, because they are my parents"
>
> "I do so because they are my parents"

That's all, I think. ("Of course" is fine, but gives less detail)